# Login Dropbox account in chromium browser returns the Blank URL while generating the Access token

Tags: dropbox, chromium, dropbox-api, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have developed the `WPF project with OAuth for Dropbox`. I have faced some difficulties in the Access token generation process recently (It worked fine, a couple of days earlier).

I have used the **Chromium browser** for this process. While login with Dropbox account in chromium-browser `returns the Blank URL instead of the Redirect URL with Access token`.

> Url: https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=abcxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https:...
>
> CefSharp  version: 37

Please suggest me to how to proceed furtherly and let me know if any further information required from my end.

Comment: Are you serious when you say your using version `37`? That's years out of date. They probably dropped support for old browsers

Comment: Yes, Due to some project internal reasons, we are still using version 37.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Login-Dropbox-account-in-chromium-browser-returns-the-Blank-URL/m-p/308613 ]

Comment: Version 37 is just too old, best bet is to upgrade.

Comment: @amaitland: Thank you and could you please update which is the latest version that is compatible with .NET 4.5 Framework version.

Comment: Version `67` and the soon to be released version `69` require `.Net 4.5.2`.